# regexp containing ^ and * will lose one character?

Tags: javascript, regex

JS demo:

```
// words not ending with abc
var r = new RegExp("(.*)[^(?:abc)]$")
var s = 'zzxxxyy'
console.log(r.exec(s))
```

output:

`[ 'zzxxxyy', 'zzxxxy', index: 0, input: 'zzxxxyy' ]`

why is `group(1)` `zzxxxy`, rather than `zzxxxyy`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/sIbCyd/3 - read the Explanation panel, *carefully*.

Comment: You cannot use groups inside [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^(?:abc)]` matches a single character that is not `(` or `?` or `:` or `a` or `b` or `c` or `)`. It's equivalent to `[^)(abc:?]`.

Comment: So if want to use regexp to match strings not ending with `abc`, rather than `(.*)[^a][^b][^c]`, how to do it?  `(.*)(?!abc)` will still match `1abc`.

Comment: @JiacaiLiu `if (!/abc$/.test(str))`. Negate the result in the JS code instead.

Comment: It works but in my situation, only regexp can be used.

Comment: Then you can use `/^(?![\s\S]*abc$)/`.